# Amp-twitter doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: html, amp-html

I am having a problem with Amp plugin , I use this to show tweets :

```
<amp-twitter width="390"
          height="330"
          layout="responsive"
          data-tweetid="855178606556856320">
      </amp-twitter>
```

and I also included these:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-twitter" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-twitter-0.1.js"></script>

<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

it opens on mozilla firefox, but it shows this error on chrome :

```
**Error: Parent origin mismatch: null, file://​​​
    at ia.g.assert (log.js:318)
    at window.draw3p (integration.js:830)
    at frame.html:9
g.assert @ log.js:324
integration.js:552 Uncaught Error: Parent origin mismatch: null, file://​​​
    at ia.g.assert (log.js:318)
    at window.draw3p (integration.js:830)
    at frame.html:9**
```

Comment: bug report: https://github.com/ampproject